# Add score using score module

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm working on a game, collecting points by pressing on images. Pressing images and respawning new ones is no problem but adding points to the score causes some problems. When I press on the images the score doesn't get updated with the amount of points. I'm using this score module http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/12/10/tutorial-howtosavescores/

```lua
local score_mod = require( "score" )
math.randomseed( os.time() )

local scoreText = score_mod.init({
fontSize = 70,
font = native.systemFont,
x = display.contentCenterX + 50,
y = display.contentCenterY + 170,
filename = "scorefile.txt"
})
scoreText:setTextColor( (232/255), (216/255), (32/255) )

local function Game ()

    local images ={
    {name = "Icon.png", points = 1},
    {name = "Icon-mdpi.png", points = 2},
    {name = "Icon-xhdpi.png", points = 3},
    {name = "Icon-ldpi.png", points = 4},
    {name = "Icon-Small-50.png", points = 5}
    }

    local numRows = 3
    local numCols = 2

    local blockWidth = display.contentCenterX / 2.2
    local blockHeight = display.contentCenterY / 2
    local row
    local col
    local imgDataArray = {}

    function imagePress (event)
        if event.phase == "began" then
            local x = event.target.x
            local y = event.target.y 
            event.target:removeSelf()

            score_mod.score = score_mod.score + images[event.target.imgNumber].points

            function nextImages(x, y)  
            local nextRandomImg = math.random(1,5)
            local nextImage = display.newImage(images[nextRandomImg].name, x, y)
            nextImage:addEventListener( "touch", imagePress )
            nextImage.imgNumber = nextRandomImg
            table.insert(imgDataArray, image)
        end

        local nextDelay = function() return nextImages(x, y) end
        timer.performWithDelay( 2000, nextDelay, 1 )

        end

        return true
    end

    function makeImage()    
    for row = 1, numRows do
        for col = 1, numCols do
            local x = (col - 1) * blockWidth + 120
            local y = (row + 1) * blockHeight - 160

            local randomImage = math.random(1, 5)
            local image = display.newImage(images[randomImage].name, x, y)
            image.imgNumber = randomImage
            image.imgX = x
            image.imgY = y
            image:addEventListener( "touch", imagePress )
            table.insert(imgDataArray, image)
            end
        end
    end

    makeImage()

end
Game()
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be actually using `score_mod.set`?

Comment: That's also what I initially thought but it gave me an error. attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'set' (a function value)

Comment: `score_mod.set` is a function, you call it with the new score value. Or you use `score_mod.add` to add a value to the score. The linked page talks about this at the end and links to a sample app.

Comment: Alright, now I know what you meant. All what I had to do was to use this **score_mod.add(images[event.target.imgNumber].points)** instead of score_mod.score = score_mod.score + images[event.target.imgNumber].points

Comment: If this question has been answered in comments you should either post and accept an answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **score_mod.add(images[event.target.imgNumber].points)** instead of score_mod.score = score_mod.score + images[event.target.imgNumber].points